# Integral of modulus is the modulus of the integral iff arguments are constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

I'm sure this has been asked before but I can't find it and it's bugging me. I'm reading Voison's Hodge theory book and I ran into this elementary inequality that I realize I don't understand as well as I should: if $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ is continuous (or as differentiable as you like, it doesn't matter) then integrating along a circle centered at $z_0\in \mathbb C$ and parametrizing in the usual way, the following inequality holds: $$\left|\int_0^1 f(z_0+e^{2\pi it})\mathrm dt\right|\le \int_0^1|f(z_0+e^{2\pi it})|\mathrm dt.$$

The claim is that equality holds if and only if the argument of $f(z_0+e^{2\pi it})$ is constant. This is of course sufficient for equality, but for the life of me I can't prove necessity. I think I'm just having a bad day but I need to know **why**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that we have equality. By multiplying $f$ with the right phase, we may wlog  assume that the integral on the LHS is nonnegative even without absolut value. Thus, one gets in this case
$$ \int_0^1 \ \operatorname{Re}( f(z_0 + e^{2\pi i t})) dt = \int_0^1 \ \sqrt{ \operatorname{Re}(f(z_0 + e^{2\pi i t}))^2 + \operatorname{Im}(f(z_0 + e^{2\pi i t}))^2} dt.$$
This can only be an equality if the imaginary part vanishes identically and the real part is nonnegative. I.e. exactly that the argument is constant.